# How can I set a version number in a .NET project file using Ruby/Rake?

Tags: ruby, xml, rake, albacore

We are moving our build environment from NAnt to Rake. Some NAnt tasks have to be rewritten. In this case, [XmlPoke task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html) (part of the NAntContrib library). With Ruby this can be made quite easily.

Comment: Let me know if I changed the title too much. I'm going to answer the question I thought you were asking: how to update an assembly version number. But I see from your answer, that you're interested in general XML updating (a copy of the XML poke task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question I thought you were asking: how to update an assembly version number. But I see from your answer, that you're interested in general XML updating (a copy of the XML poke task).

#### How to update the assembly version using Ruby/Rake/Albacore?

My recommendation for .NET projects is to always update the version in the [assembly info file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo.aspx). Not by directly editing the `csproj`. And Albacore contains methods for doing that, use the [AssemblyInfo Task](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/wiki/AssemblyInfo-Task).

#### How to recreate the NAnt xmlpoke task?

I actually wrote a couple of .NET specific [file update tasks](https://github.com/anthonymastrean/fileupdatetasks#appconfig) in the style of Albacore's custom tasks. I called them `apprc` (for rewriting CLI resource files, which have goofy encoding problems). And `appconfig`, which really works on any XML file.

Info is in the readme, but it works a little different than the xmlpoke task.

```
appconfig :taskname do |x|
  x.files = FileList['relative/wildcard/path/to/*.exe.config']
  x.replacements = {
    'some/x/path/expression' => 'replacment-value',
    'another/x/path/expression' => 'another-replacment!'
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    require 'albacore/tasks/versionizer'
    require 'semver'
    require 'rexml/document'
    include REXML

    Albacore::Tasks::Versionizer.new(:versioning)

    ver = SemVer.find
    ASSEMBLY_VERSION = "#{ SemVer.new(ver.major, ver.minor, ver.patch).format "%M.%m.%p"}" + ".0"

    class XmlPoke
      attr_accessor :xml_file_path
      def initialize xmlfilepath
        @xml_file_path = xmlfilepath
      end
      def pokeelement xpath, value
        file = File.open(xml_file_path, 'r')
        xmldoc = Document.new(file)
        xpathnode = XPath.first(xmldoc, xpath)
        xpathnode.text = value
        formatter = REXML::Formatters::Default.new
        File.open(xml_file_path, 'w') do |result|
          formatter.write(xmldoc, result)
        end
      end
    end

    desc "Sets Application Version in project file"
    task :outlookproj do
      projectfilepath = "dotnet_project_path/dotnet_project_name.csproj"
      xpath = "/Project/PropertyGroup/ApplicationVersion"
      value = "#{ASSEMBLY_VERSION}"
      poker = XmlPoke.new projectfilepath
      poker.pokeelement xpath, value
    end
```